# Lidar Elevations Data

Tags: elevation, lidar

I am trying to acquire a method of detecting sub cm elevation without manually measuring from the field.  Can LIDAR data produce this for me?  Example:  A 1500 foot long pipe conveying water from one point to another.  I need to know the rise and falls of the terrain where the pipe will be lying.  Can LIDAR produce this for me?  I am needing coverage for agricultural land throughout the Delta.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Sub-centimeter elevation? No.

This [article](http://www.pobonline.com/CDA/Archives/d3ab817cac0f6010VgnVCM100000f932a8c0) provides a good overview of LiDAR and the associated errors (Range, Position & Orientation).

Operationally, when working with LiDAR data we assume a potential 5-10cm vertical and horizontal error. At times it may be much more accurate, but it's not sub-cm.

Comment: So, if there was a possible .5 fall of elevation along 1500 ft. LIDAR would not be able to determine that for me?

Comment: LiDAR will not provide you with .5cm accuracy over any length. For this level of precision you would need field surveys.

Comment: Also, 5 mm accuracy doesn't make much sense, when you talk about measuring relief of landscape. Field has microrelief, vegetation etc, so height may vary more, than is your desired accuracy.